# Where to get ElasticSearch document version using NEST

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

It should be in the `Hits[i].Version` but that is always null when I look at the `ISearchResponse`.

I've also set the `.EnableMetrics` on the `ConnectionSettings` object but no luck as the version is always null.

I have double checked ElasticSearch and the document versions are incrementing fine in there.

So has anyone successfully managed to view the document version please using Nest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
    [Test]
    public void WithVersion()
    {
        var queryResults = this.Client.Search<ElasticsearchProject>(s=>s
            .Version()
            .MatchAll()
        );
        Assert.True(queryResults.IsValid);
        Assert.Greater(queryResults.Total, 0);
        Assert.True(queryResults.Hits.All(h => !h.Version.IsNullOrEmpty()));
    }
```

Comment: That's the one, cheers Rob. Setting `.Version()` on the SearchDescriptor did the trick.